# creating navigation & page in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onclick, navigation

Apologies in advance is this is a duplicate. I'm new here and new to javascript. I'll begin by describing what I am aiming to do, then show the code.

Basically. I have a HTML page with a simple navigation bar (the usual ul li arrangement). When one of the options is clicked, it will show the relevant 'page' (which are  tags) by removing the .hide class on the target article, and adding the .hide class to the page that was visible. Previously I simply just used the 'getElementByID' to grab each element by id, showing whats' meant to show and hiding whats meant to be hidden.

As you can imagine, it ends up in repeating that many times in a function. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this. The way I thought I'd try would be to grab all the navigation elements and place them in an array, then grab all the 'page' elements and put them in an array. When the option in the navigation is clicked, it returns the index position in the array, which can be compared the the index position of the pages in the other array. If they match, remove the .hide class to make the 'page' visible. Anything else that doesnt match, add the .hide class to the remaining 'page' elements

Here is my attempt so far:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html> <html> <head> <title>Practice to improve javascripting</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/practice.js"></script> </head>

<body onload="indexNum()"> <div id="pageContainer"> <ul> <a href="" class="select" id="test"><li>Test</li></a> <a href="" id="yay"><li>Test</li></a> <a href="" id="woo"><li>Test</li></a> </ul>

<article id="one"> <h4>Page one</h4> <p>Page one is now displayed</p> </article>

<article id="two" class="hide"> <h4>Page two</h4> <p></p> </article>

<article id="three" class="hide"> <h4>Page three</h4> <p></p> </article>

</div><!-- end of pageContainer div-->

</body> </html>
```

CSS:

```
/*CSS Document */

    body { background-color:whiteSmoke;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; margin:0; padding:0;      
    }

    #pageContainer {margin: 20px auto 40px auto;
    padding:0; width: 600px; height:auto;
    background-color:snow;
    border: 1px solid gainsboro; border-radius: 3px; /*end of set-up code*/
    }

    /*navbar styles*/

    ul {
        background-color:white; 
        border: 1px solid violet;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 550px; height: 20px;
        margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
        list-style-type:none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        float:left;
        width:33%; height:20px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .select li {
        background-color:violet;
        color: snow; font-weight:bold;
    }

    a {color: black;}

    /*page styles*/

    article {
        width: 600px; height: 400px;
        border-top: 1px solid gainsboro;
        margin:0; padding:0;
    }

    h4, p {margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px}

    .hide {display:none;}
```

and here is my mess of javascript lol:

```
    //create global variables
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName

('a');

var page = document.getElementsByTagName

('article');


/*create a function that will be called on 

page load to find the index position of the 

navigation buttons:*/

function indexNum(){
    nav; //calling the nav global variable

    //search array for index positions
    for(var index = 0; index < nav.length; index++) {

       //store index number in variable?
       nav[index].indexNumber = index;

       //now search array of page index position
       for(var indexPages = 0; indexPages < page.length; indexPages++){

           //store index number in variable?
           nav[indexPages].indexedNumber = indexPages;

           //function to return index of element clicked
           nav[index].onclick = function() {

               if (this.indexNumber == page[indexPages]) {
                   page.className = "";
               } else if (this.indexNumber !== page[indexPages]) {
                   page.className = "hide";
               }

          }
     }
}
```

I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but I want to be able to add as many options on the navigation bar, with the corresponding pages. Even add as many navigation bars (for sub navigation on a page) with as many sub pages. So this is the reason for my madness lol.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you add function inside for loop and use index in that function you need to wrap that function with closure because for loop don't create new scope, so the index have the last value when you execute those functions.

Comment: Martin - just curious if my solution worked for you, or if you had any other questions?  If it worked for you, could you please mark it as the answer?  Thanks!

Comment: @HowardRenollet Is this kind of hiding and showing a good use of tabs/content on a site for example? Thank you for your reply I will for sure learn from it. How about using this for a one-pager and just showing sections of the site inside a header and footer and nothing else? The rest of the content would be indexed for sure but the site would take longer to load initially, unless loading of next section is deferred. What do you think? Bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here it goes.  I commented every step of the way in the JavaScript so you can learn exactly what's going on here.

This is completely dynamic.  You can add and remove articles as needed, and your navigation menu will update automatically and without any limitations.

```js
var doStuff = function () {
  // Get all of the articles
  var articles = document.getElementsByTagName("article");

  // Define an empty array to hold the id's of the articles 
  var navIds = [];

  // Loop through the articles
  for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {

    // Get the classes for the current article
    var classes = articles[i].classList;

    var hidden = false;

    // Loop through the class list for the current article
    for (var a = 0; a < classes.length; a++) {

      // If the current class equals "hide"
      if (classes[a] === "hide") {

        // Set the variable "hidden" to true
        hidden = true;

        // Get out of the loop
        break;
      }
    }

    // If the article is hidden, add the ID to the navIds array so we can add it to the navigation
    if (hidden) {
      navIds.push(articles[i].id);
    }
  }

  // If there are hidden articles
  if (navIds.length > 0) {

    // Clear the navigation
    document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML = "";
  }

  // Loop through the navIds
  for (var i = 0; i < navIds.length; i++) {

    // Get the nav element (ul)
    var navElem = document.getElementById("nav");

    // Create a new li element
    var liElem = document.createElement("li");

    // Add the li element to the nav (ul) element
    navElem.appendChild(liElem);

    // Create a new a element
    var aElem = document.createElement("a");

    // Set the href on the new a element
    aElem.href = "#"

    // Set the "data-article" attribute to the id of the article to show when clicked
    aElem.setAttribute("data-article", navIds[i]);

    // Here, we're going to set the navigation title to the contents of the h4 element in the article
    // Get the current article
    var article = document.getElementById(navIds[i]);

    // Get the children of the current article
    var children = article.childNodes;

    // Define an empty variable to hold the h4 element when we find it
    var h4Elem;

    // Loop through the children of the current article
    for (var a = 0; a < children.length; a++) {

      // If the current child is an h4 element
      if (typeof children[a].tagName !== "undefined" && children[a].tagName.toLowerCase() === "h4") {

        // Set the h4Elem variable to the current child element
        h4Elem = children[a];

        // Get out of the loop
        break;
      }
    }

    // Since we defined h4Elem as an empty variable, we need to make sure it's a valid HTMLElement object
    if (h4Elem instanceof HTMLElement) {

      // Set the Inner HTML of the new a element to the Inner HTML of the article's h4 element
      aElem.innerHTML = h4Elem.innerHTML;
    }

    // Add the new a element to the new li element in the navigation
    liElem.appendChild(aElem);

    // Add a click event handler on the new a element in the navigation
    aElem.addEventListener("click", function () {

      // Get all of the articles
      var articles = document.getElementsByTagName("article");

      // Loop through the articles
      for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {

        // Get the classes for the current article
        var classes = articles[i].classList;

        // Define a hidden variable and set it to false
        var hidden = false;

        // Loop through the classes of the current article
        for (var a = 0; a < classes.length; a++) {

          // If the class is "hide"
          if (classes[a] === "hide") {

            // Set the hidden variable to true
            hidden = true;

            // Get out of the loop
            break;
          }
        }

        // If the article is not hidden
        if (!hidden) {

          // hide it
          articles[i].classList.add("hide");
        }
      }

      // Get the id of the article to show
      var elemIdToShow = this.getAttribute("data-article");

      // Get the element to show
      var elemToShow = document.getElementById(elemIdToShow);

      // Remove the hidden class from it
      elemToShow.classList.remove("hide");

      // Re-run the doStuff() function to regenerate the navigation and event handlers
      doStuff();
    });
  }
}
// Run the doStuff() function
doStuff();
```

```css
/* Your original CSS, I didn't change anything */
body {background-color: whiteSmoke;font-family: Verdana, Geneva,sans-serif;font-size: 12pt;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#pageContainer {margin: 20px auto 40px auto;padding: 0;width: 600px;height: auto;background-color: snow;border: 1px solid gainsboro;border-radius: 3px;}
ul { background-color: white;border: 1px solid violet;border-radius: 3px;width: 550px; height: 20px;margin: 15px auto 15px auto;list-style-type: none;padding: 0;}
li {float: left;width: 33%;height: 20px;text-align: center;}
.select li {background-color: violet;color: snow;font-weight: bold;}
a {color: black;}
article {width: 600px;height: 400px;border-top: 1px solid gainsboro;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
h4, p {margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;}
.hide {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="pageContainer">
  <ul id="nav"><!-- Empty ul for dynamic navigation --></ul>
  <!-- Each article is a separate "page" -->
  <article id="one">
    <h4>Page one</h4>
    <p>Page one is now displayed</p>
  </article>
  <article id="two" class="hide">
    <h4>Page two</h4>
    <p>Page two is now displayed</p>
  </article>
  <article id="three" class="hide">
    <h4>Page three</h4>
    <p>Page three is now displayed</p>
  </article>
</div>
```